# How to disable direct url unless linked from another page?

Tags: php, hyperlink, hotlinking

I have a page called snow.php.  I want to disable people from being able to see my webpage if they type in www.mysite.com/snow.php  unless they are linked from another page.  So if I have another page called  about.php and link to snow.php they'll be able to see it.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It seems like a bizarre feature to want. One approach might be to only serve the page if the request contains a referer header (note that I'm not certain this would reliably work for all browsers), but that would be possible for a user with some basic tech savvy to spoof. Does the solution need to be secure?

Comment: I have a page which can only be accessed if they enter a password I give them from the previous page.

Comment: Ok.... so I got no help on this.  Anyone???

Comment: @sfdevotion You got your answers. The fact that you can't understand them means you need to hit the books

Answer (score 0):

What you want is how to prevent hotlinking. Here is a small tutorial: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/smarter-way-to-prevent-image-hotlinking-with-htaccess/

Comment: Uh, by my reading this isn't what the OP is asking for at all. He wants the page to only be accessible if the user *did* follow a link from another site.

Comment: The hotlinking mechanism can be used to filter for specific site. In that tutorial there is a section about allowing specific domains.

Comment: And I have no idea how to use this. Honestly, I need someone to hold my hand cause this is going over my head.

Answer (score 0):

This method isn't 100% reliable, but you can use $HTTP_SERVER_VARS['HTTP_REFERER'] to get the current page that the user came from to access snow.php.

Comment: How should I use this though?

Comment: `$HTTP_SERVER_VARS` is not recommended and is removed as of PHP 5.4 . He should user `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

Comment: I have no idea what I'm looking at... help?